# Consume Feign Client Response Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-feign

I have a Feign Client to get response from External Api.
Below is the code for Feign Client

```
@FeignClient(name = "demo", url = "http://localhost:8080")
public interface DemoClient {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/", consumes = "application/json")
public Response getPayANorLOS(@RequestHeader("AUTH_TOKEN") String token, @RequestBody MyRequest reqBodyProp);
}
```

I am consuming this using below code

```
try{
   Response response =DemoClient.getPayANorLOS(headerProp, reqBodyProp);
}catch (Exception e) {
                    //we need to log the error
                    log.error("Unable to get", e.getMessage());
                    subscriber.onError(e);
}
```

I always get an exception. I also logged the request and i see the response

```
---> POST http://localhost:8080/api/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
AUTH_TOKEN: SBAWCS01:ElHfgB9ESd8Du8pIYKHxxPOWkT26GLf4zhmRVk
Content-Length: 365
---> END HTTP (365-byte body)
<--- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (547ms)
connection: close
content-length: 232
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' https; script-src https: 'self' 
'unsafe-inline'; connect-src https: 'self'
content-type: application/json
date: Thu, 16 Aug 2018 19:17:08 GMT
server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
{"validThru":"11/22","type":"Demo","brand":"TIM"}
<--- END HTTP (232-byte body)
```

Why I always get Exception. Please Help.
Also the exception is null.

Comment: could you post the stack trace of the exception you are getting? you can change the log statement to something like `log.error("Unable to get", e);` could be helpful in finding a solution

Comment: Hi Bankole, I changed the Response to My Class Object and it started working. that's really weird. i will inform you if it fails. Thank you very much